# Exception slips through try...catch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, fs

I have a subroutine in Node to load configuration etc before proper application starts. It turns out that in case file is not found, the exception fails to be catched and breaks the app.

Relevant code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class FileParser {
    static configure(filename) {
        let file;
        try {
            file = this.loadFileSync(filename);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`File ${filename} not found`);
        }

        // ...
    }

    static loadFileSync(filename) {
        fs.accessSync(filename, fs.F_OK);
        return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    }
}
```

If file is not found the `fs.accessSync()` will throw an exception. Good, as it's there to safeguard `fs.readFileSync()`. But I thought that this exception will propagate up through calling functions and can be catched there - hence the `try...catch` in `configure()`.

I don't want to resolve the exception in `loadFileSync()` as it is used elsewhere and functions calling `loadFileSync()` are to deal with the exception differently. So, what's the proper way to safeguard against file not found here and bubbling exceptions in general?

Comment: can you try : 
put try/catch in loadFileSync and then inside catch throw the same error. This way you put try/catch on accessSync and then the error is thrown will be caught by configure. Not sure it will work

Comment: Yes, try...catch around fs.accessSync() helps. But I don't really know why it works and what's general way to do it. I'll be grateful if you could elaborate.

Comment: Well I can't comment too much on the implementation of "accessSync" method and I believe that the implementation is throwing some unhandled error and is not actually sync but a loop and hence you are not able to get the error but encapsulating the same method in try/catch forces to capture any unhandled error.

Comment: if the fix worked, please accept the answer so that it helps others. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```js
const fs = require('fs');

class FileParser {
    static configure(filename) {
        let file;
        try {
            file = this.loadFileSync(filename);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`File ${filename} not found`);
        }

        // ...
    }

    static loadFileSync(filename) {
        try {
        fs.accessSync(filename, fs.F_OK);
        } catch(error) {
            throw(error);
        }
        return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    }
}
```

This may solve the problem and the reason why you are facing this problem may be because of the implementation of accessSync method itself.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Still, I don't know why. Perhaps you are right about accessSync implementation. Sorry for delay in accepting it, I hoped that someone would supply the answer that explains the issue fully.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, there are two ways you can handle exception here.

**Method 1: Using Promise**

```
class FileParser {

      static configure(filename) {
        let file;
        loadFileSync(filename).then(function(result){
          // 'result' will contain whatever you have 
          // resolved in loadFileSync promise
          file = result;
        }).catch(function(err){
          // Handle err here
        });
      }

      static loadFileSync(filename) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          fs.accessSync(filename, fs.F_OK);
          // Check if everything is ok.
          // If yes
          return resolve(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'));
          // Else
          return reject(err);
        });
      }
    }
```

**Method 2: Using callbacks**

```
class FileParser {
  static configure(filename) {
    let file;

    this.loadFileSync(filename, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`File ${filename} not found`);
        // return or throw
      }

      file = result;
    });
  }

  static loadFileSync(filename, cb) {
    fs.accessSync(filename, fs.F_OK);
    // Check if everything is ok.
    // If yes
    return cb(null, fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'));
    // Else
    return cb(err);
  }
}
```

Hope you find it useful!